# Adicionar HTML com JavaScript e Permanecer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, append

Estou querendo que seja possível adicionar e depois quando atualize a página ele permaneça salvo no meu HTML.

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #56B8BD;
  max-height: 70px;
}

.menu ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 1%;
}

button {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 56px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-top: 0.25%;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="principal">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li> Barra Menu</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <button onclick="adicionar()">+</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    function adicionar() {
      $("body").append("<nav><ul><li> Novo Menu Adicionado</li></ul></nav>");
      $("nav").addClass("menu")
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas você quer que essa nova `div` seja adicionada ao seu arquivo HTML depois de gerada?

Comment: Você precisa persistir essas alterações em algum lugar, seja em banco de dados, localStorage, sessão, memória, arquivo em disco, etc, depende das suas necessidades.

Comment: Seria isto mesmo mas n sei como fazer isso se vocês puderem ajudar

Comment: Que tal localstorage? veja se funciona ai http://kithomepage.com/sos/adicionado.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para configurar sua conexão ao Banco Mysql em PHP:

```
<?php
   $db_name = "[Nome do seu banco]";
   $db_user = "[Nome de usuario do seu banco]";
   $db_password = "[Senha do banco]";
   $db_host = "[Host do banco]";

   $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

   if(!$conn)
        echo "Erro na conexão";

   //Para inserir a quantidade de DIV's
   $sql = "INSERT INTO [Nome da sua tabela] ([nome da coluna])
               VALUES ([valor a ser adicionado])";

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "Sucesso!";
   } else {
      echo "Error";
   }

   //Para buscar um valor no banco
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM [Nome da sua tabela]";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   //Dae voce usa a var result para manipular os dados do BD
?>
```

Comment: vou dar uma olhada aqui

Comment: Deu certinho vleu amigo